# Cannot use github as code source in Deployement Center

Tags: azure

I cannot use github as source in azure app service deployment center.
when I select github, the screen turns into white only
[image]

Its working fine when I use Deployment Center (classic)
[image]

here is the details of the app service

```
{
    "name": "AppServicePlan-B1",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
    "kind": "app",
    "location": "Southeast Asia",
    "properties": {
        "name": "AppServicePlan-B1",
        "workerSize": 0,
        "workerSizeId": 0,
        "workerTierName": null,
        "numberOfWorkers": 1,
        "currentWorkerSize": 0,
        "currentWorkerSizeId": 0,
        "currentNumberOfWorkers": 1,
        "status": 0,
        "adminSiteName": null,
        "hostingEnvironment": null,
        "hostingEnvironmentProfile": null,
        "maximumNumberOfWorkers": 3,
        "planName": "VirtualDedicatedPlan",
        "adminRuntimeSiteName": null,
        "computeMode": 1,
        "siteMode": null,
        "geoRegion": "Southeast Asia",
        "perSiteScaling": false,
        "maximumElasticWorkerCount": 1,
        "numberOfSites": 27,
        "hostingEnvironmentId": null,
        "isSpot": false,
        "spotExpirationTime": null,
        "freeOfferExpirationTime": null,
        "tags": null,
        "kind": "app",
        "reserved": false,
        "isXenon": false,
        "hyperV": false,
        "targetWorkerCount": 0,
        "targetWorkerSizeId": 0,
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "webSiteId": null,
        "existingServerFarmIds": null,
        "kubeEnvironmentProfile": null,
        "azBalancing": false
    },
    "sku": {
        "name": "B1",
        "tier": "Basic",
        "size": "B1",
        "family": "B",
        "capacity": 1
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
There is an error upon checking the console
[image]

Comment: It works fine on my side. Are you sure it's not a network problem?

Comment: @BowmanZhu, how can I debug if its network problem? My commit on github has been deployed successfully using the classic deployment.

Comment: Can you share your app service configuration (such as the service plan. os and so on)? I want to try to reproduce

Comment: @BowmanZhu I updated the post, I included the details of the app service. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We able to fix this issue. we set value for stack on the app service and it works perfectly now.